# google script loop copy to loop row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi sorry this is probably a very newbie question, I am teaching myself and can't figure out how to google the answer to this one.

I have a loop in google sheets that goes through each field and updates some cells which pull info from a website that I then need to copy across into each row of the loop.  It seems to be working through the loop okay however when trying to copy i cant get it into the correct row.

Im sure its something very simple hoping someone out there can point me in the right direction.  I'm pretty sure its to do with the code at line 34 but can't figure out how to correct it.

```
function myLoop() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var Lsheet = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Loop'), true);
    var rangeData = Lsheet.getDataRange();
    var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
    var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
    var dataRange = Lsheet.getRange(2,1, lastRow-1, lastColumn-1);
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    var len = data.length;

    var i = 0

    for (i; i < len; i++) {
        var row = data[i];
        var player = row[4]
        var prop = row[6]
        var number = row[7]
        var overodds = row[8]
        var underodds = row[9]
        var overreq = row[10]
        var underreq = row[11];

        if(prop = "Points"){
            ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Stats'), true);
            ss.getRange('B1').activate();
            ss.getRange("B1").setValue(player);
            ss.getRange('AB5').activate();
            ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Loop'), true);
            ss.getRange(overreq).activate();
            ss.getRange('Stats!AB5').copyTo(ss.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
            ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Stats'), true);
            ss.getRange('AB6').activate();
            ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Loop'), true);
            ss.getRange(underreq).activate();
            ss.getRange('Stats!AB6').copyTo(ss.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello 5414121, I am somewhat confused as to what you are trying to accomplish inside the for-loop. Could you please explain that to me (which data should be moved, from which place to which place). Thanks!

Comment: The loop copies information into the sheet "stats" which has a bunch of fields update I then wish to move some of that updated info in cells AB5 & AB6 back into the last two columns of the original sheet

Comment: @54114121 I have published an answer with some code improvements and corrections. Kindly let me know if that works for you, and if it doesn't, please tell me the exact error/issue you get. Furthermore, could you describe what's in the `overreq`, `underreq` variables? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifications of the original code:

1. Corrected an **error** in line 24. In your original post, you are using `=` ([assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators)) to compare your variables. However, you want to use `==` ([equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality_operators)).
2. Added missing semicolons. Although not necessary, makes for good, consistent style and may prevent some errors.
3. Moved `i` declaration inside the for-loop. Makes for cleaner, safer code.
4. Modified for-loop body so that it uses ranges and `setValue()`, `getValue()` methods to copy data.

```js
function myLoop() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var Lsheet = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Loop'), true);
    var rangeData = Lsheet.getDataRange();
    var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
    var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
    var dataRange = Lsheet.getRange(2,1, lastRow-1, lastColumn-1);
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    var len = data.length;

    var statsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Stats');
    var loopSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Loop');

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var row = data[i];
        var player = row[4];
        var prop = row[6];
        var number = row[7];
        var overodds = row[8];
        var underodds = row[9];
        var overreq = row[10];
        var underreq = row[11];

        if (prop == "Points") {
          statsSheet.getRange('B1').setValue(player);

          loopSheet.getRange(overreq).setValues(
            statsSheet.getRange('AB5').getValues()
          );

          loopSheet.getRange(underreq).setValues(
            statsSheet.getRange('AB6').getValues()
          );

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps @carlesgg97 that makes it much easier to follow! 

I am still just getting one error "Range not found (line 30, file "Code"" which is the "loopSheet.getRange(overreq).setValues(" line sorry I have moved things around a bit on my end.

both the overreq and underreq fields are number variables

Comment: thanks again @carlesgg97.   I just needed to change that line to reflect row and column, not sure if this is the cleanest way but...     loopSheet.getRange(i+2,10).setValues(

Comment: Hey @5414121, that is a good solution! I also suggest you clean up some of the variables - as some of them are no longer needed... Glad you were able to fix your issue!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
var currentRow = ss.getActiveRange().getRow();
var currentCol = ss.getActiveRange().getColumn();
.
.
.
ss.getRange('State!AB5').copyTo(ss.getRange(currentRow+1, currentCol), 
SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```